# redirect value from one view to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to pass selected table row values from one view to another.
My code looks like this.

```
<table id="tableid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="Sno">S No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
    @foreach (var sd in Model.Details)
    {

      <tr id="trid">
        <td>@sd .Id</td>
        <td>@sd .Name</td>
        <td>@sd .Status</td>
        <td>

          <a id="actionId"   onclick="Clickfn(@sd .Id)"  >
          </a>
          <script>
            function Clickfn(Id) {
var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateCam", "Campaignboard", new {id = -1})';
 window.location.href = url.replace('-1', Id);
               }
          </script>

          </td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to pass selected row Details from this view to another view .
How i can achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the ActionLink helper (and dump the javascript)

```
@foreach (var sd in Model.Details)
{
  ....
  <td>@Html.ActionLink("SomeTextLabel", "UpdateCam", "Campaignboard", new { id = sd .Id })</td>
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just append the string.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateCam", "Campaignboard")';
window.location.href = url + '/' + Id;
```

By default based on route configuration, the query will be routed to `id`.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function Clickfn(Id, Name, Status) 
 {
    var url = "@Url.Action("UpdateCam", "Campaignboard", new {id = _Id, name=_Name, status=_Status})".replace("_Id", Id).replace("_Name", Name).replace("_Status", Status);
    window.location.href = url;               
 }
```

Your action will be,

```
Public ActionResult UpdateCam(int id, string name, string status)
{
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: By doing this,,its going to controller only..i want to get row values in another view.

Comment: So first u hit the action in the controller and redirect to your view